# cv2.imshow cannot display Windows in ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

ubuntu uses pycharm to run the program, which calls cv2.imshow and cv2.VideoCapture. But I can't show the window, the program keeps running, but there is no window. And after the window is displayed and then closed, the program is stuck like a dead, not to go down.

All opencv-python packages are installed with the same version. matplotlib is also installed。Related functions such as cv2.waitkey are also written, and the code can be sure that there are no related problems, and it can run perfectly on Windows 10

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.